# 'Activity.ManagedQuery(Uri, string[], string, string[], string)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I got this message while compiling this code for Xamarin.Android:

```
"E:\_MyFiles\Projects\C#\TelegramHack\TelegramHack.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  App.cs(53,26): warning CS0618: 'Activity.ManagedQuery(Uri, string[], string, string[], string)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'
[E:\_MyFiles\Projects\C#\**PrivateContent**\**PrivateContent**.csproj]

var ctks = new List<Contact>();
            var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
            string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number};
            var cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.MoveToFirst ()) {
                do {
                        ctks.Add(new Contact {Name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [1])), Number = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [2]))});
                }  while (cursor.MoveToNext());
            }
            return ctks.ToArray();
```

Comment: _...I got this message..._ Nice, what is your question? The error _is obsolete: 'deprecated':_ explains all...

Comment: I want to use a method that isn't deprecated

Comment: I tried that @bub , Got this error:  error CS0103: The name 'GetContentResolver' does not exist in the current context

Comment: How to use `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);` in Xamarin?

Comment: As you were asking for Xamarin: Instread of `ManagedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null)` use `ContentResolver.Query(uri, proj, null, null, null)`